# convert Int64Index to Int

Tags: pandas

I'm iterating through a dataframe (called hdf) and applying changes on a row by row basis. hdf is sorted by group_id and assigned a 1 through n rank on some criteria.

```
# Groupby function creates subset dataframes (a dataframe per distinct group_id).
grouped = hdf.groupby('group_id')

# Iterate through each subdataframe. 
for name, group in grouped:

    # This grabs the top index for each subdataframe
    index1 = group[group['group_rank']==1].index

    # If criteria1 == 0, flag all rows for removal
    if(max(group['criteria1']) == 0):    
        for x in range(rank1, rank1 + max(group['group_rank'])):
            hdf.loc[x,'remove_row'] = 1
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Int64Index'
```

I get the same error when I try to cast rank1 explicitly I get the same error:

```
rank1 = int(group[group['auction_rank']==1].index)
```

Can someone explain what is happening and provide an alternative?

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're asking. The line `index1 = group[group['group_rank']==1].index` returns what amounts to a list of all row numbers where `group_rank` is equal to 1. What would it mean to convert it to an integer?

Comment: the group_rank is unique for each group. So if there are 5 rows within a group, the group ranks will be 1 through 5.

I will eventually remove all rows from hdf where remove_row = 1. The logic to figure out whether a row ought be removed from hdf needs to be done within the groupby for loop. I need the hdf index to make changes that persist to hdf, not the group dataframe. 

The loc function takes an int not an Int64Index.

Comment: Do you want to remove the entire group if `max(group['criteria1'] == 0`?

Comment: I do for this criteria but I need to remove specific rows within group for other criteria later on.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer to your specific question is that `index1` is an Int64Index (basically a list), even if it has one element. To get that one element, you can use `index1[0]`.

But there are better ways of accomplishing your goal. If you want to remove all of the rows in the "bad" groups, you can use `filter`:

```
hdf = hdf.groupby('group_id').filter(lambda group: group['criteria1'].max() != 0)
```

If you only want to remove certain rows within matching groups, you can write a function and then use `apply`:

```
def filter_group(group):
    if group['criteria1'].max() != 0:
        return group
    else:
        return group.loc[other criteria here]

hdf = hdf.groupby('group_id').apply(filter_group)
```

(If you really like your current way of doing things, you should know that `loc` will accept an index, not just an integer, so you could also do `hdf.loc[group.index, 'remove_row'] = 1`).

Comment: Let's say I have multiple removal criteria and a rather large data set. Will I improve performance by using a single group by and single for loop (per my example) or is performance on par with creating multiple functions and a groupby call for each?

Comment: If you're always grouping on the same thing, almost certainly the single groupby will be faster.

Comment: Thanks! So easy but struggled for a while before your help :)

Comment: Int64Index is basically a one-element list!
It is a genius answer! thanks.

Comment: Thanks for writing such a complete and helpful answer @EvanWright

Answer (score 10):

call tolist() on Int64Index object. Then the list can be iterated as int values.

Answer (score 1):

simply add [0] to insure the getting the first value from the index

```
rank1 = int(group[group['auction_rank']==1].index[0])
```